# Parse REST API $exist command

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm using curl to query my database with the $exist constraint as follows:

```
curl -X GET \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <myId>" \
   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <myKey>" \
   -G \
   --data-urlencode 'limit=1000' \
   --data-urlencode 'where={"someStringField":{"$exists":true}}'\
   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SomeClass
```

This **should return 1000 objects** as there are more two thousands results where "someStringField" is defined.  However, **only around 5 results are returned**.  If I run the following query I can get a thousand results:

```
curl -X GET \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <myId>" \
   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <myKey>" \
   -G \
   --data-urlencode 'limit=1000' \
   --data-urlencode 'where={"someStringField":"someValue"}'\
   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SomeClasee
```

What gives?  When I use the javascript API I have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what is wrong.  Use the Master Key when making GET requests.  The REST API key does not necessarily have permission to access all objects in Parse.  This code works.

```
curl -X GET \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <myId>" \
   -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: <myMasterKey>" \
   -G \
   --data-urlencode 'limit=1000' \
   --data-urlencode 'where={"someStringField":{"$exists":true}}'\
   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SomeClass
```